# Ionic app does not display Hindi/odia characters on Android device

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework, android-webview

I have created an Ionic App using Visual Studio 2015 IDE. In my app I need to show Odia and Hindi Font Characters. The app is working fine when i run it in Chrome using Ripple. but when I deploy it to my Device (Motorola G2 with Android 5.0.2) The Hindi/ odia fonts are coming as square boxes ! Can you please advice ?

My font face code is like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lohit-Oriya';
    src: url('Lohit-Oriya.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Open index.html in your mobile chrome browser and see if you get the same issue. Problem might be in mobile chrome browser not in ionic

Comment: in Browser it is working fine, The issue comes up  when I deploy the app to my device